# Spring Batch - Issue in understanding how reader works

Tags: spring, spring-batch

i am currently developing a application to generate csv sheet from database resultset.

i wanted to execute these job as per user request so i disable the spring.job.enabled=false and create a REST controller and calling the job from the rest controller.

but when spring is initializing, i see job method is getting called that internally calling steps and reader and so on.

i need to disable this behavior. can anyone please help

Comment: The spring boot property that should be set to false is `spring.batch.job.enabled` and not `spring.job.enabled` as you mention.

Answer (score 3):

In my setup the following works:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:batch.properties")
@Slf4j
public class BatchConfig {
 //...
}
```

Then in **batch.properties** I have set `spring.batch.job.enabled=false`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to prevent execution of batch scripts on initialization, use the following:

```
spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false
```

Comment: Thanks, however it did not worked. what i need is to stop my job to not start by itself and get called only when called from controller.